# Как решить учебное задание?

Tags: excel

Составьте двумерную таблицу значений функции f1(x,y) при условии, что независимые переменные x и y принимают значения от 1 до 10 с шагом 1. Значения переменной x разместите в столбце, значение переменной y – в строке, значение функции f1(x,y) – на пересечении соответствующих строк и столбцов.
f1(x,y)=(1+x^2)/(x^2*y^2)

Comment: @Lenka, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: создала таблицу и вбила данные,проблема с формулой

Comment: а код показать слабО?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Знак доллара позволяет множить формулу с привязкой к осям.

> =(1+$A2*$A2)/($A2*$A2*B$1*B$1)

Comment: Сокращаем: $A2*$A2=$A2^2